# The table bottom border break and print on next page, how fix it?

Tags: java, itext

I use itext+xmlworker (both v.5.5.12) for make pdf from html content and often bottom table border break and show on next page. How it fixed ?

I try use slitLate for PdfPTable instance, but it option (setSplitLate(true)) fix problem for border, but it create new trouble "crash" data in table. The table has colspan/rowspan and setSplitLate(true) move text and it styles (see arrow on the picture).

What can I do for fix it ? May be need extends form com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.table.Table and patch it..

PS. sorry for picture I cant attach it

[image: broken table]

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <p class="caption">
   <b>aaaaaaa
   </b>
  </p>
  <table class="table">
   <tr>
    <td class="tdlbg" width="20%">
     <b>Bltynbabrfnjh Ntcnjdjuj ckexfz:</b>
    </td>
    <td class="td" width="80%" colspan="4">TC-IMA-007 (2)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdlbg">
     <b>Yjvth g/g/ GB:</b>
    </td>
    <td class="td" colspan="4"> 42.00-2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdlbg">
     <b>Gjlndth;ltybt Cjjndtncndbz:</b>
    </td>
    <td class="td" colspan="4"> 25.1309(c)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdlbg">
     <b>Wtkm ntcnbhjdfybz:</b>
    </td>
    <td class="td" colspan="4">
     <p>
      <span>Ghjdthrf hf,jnjcgjcj,yjcnb cbcntvs BVF.</span>
     </p><p>
      <span>Ghjdthrf ghtljcnfdktybz 'rbgf;e</span>
      <span style="color: #000000"> </span>
      <span style="color: #000000">ntrcnjdjuj</span>
      <span style="color: #000000"> </span>
      <span style="color: #000000">ghtleght;lf.otuj cjj,otybz </span>
      <span>ghb jnrk.xtybb WD "CPIOM 1С asada asda sdasd ad".</span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdlbg" rowspan="2">
     <b>Ytj,[jlbvjcnm bvbnfwbb jnrfpjd:</b>
    </td>
    <td class="tdmbg" width="5%">
     <b>G/gs</b>
    </td>
    <td class="tdmbg" width="25%" colspan="2">
     <b>Yfpdfybt</b>
    </td>
    <td class="tdmbg" width="50%">
     <b>Jgbcfybt jnrfpf</b>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdc">1.</td>
    <td class="td" colspan="2"> Jnrfp CPIOM 1C</td>
    <td class="td">
     <p>Nbg jnrfpf^ 'ktrnhbxtcrbq</p><p>
      <span>Cbuyfk/zkjr/Hfp]`v/Rjynfrn</span>
     </p><p>
      <span>CPIOM</span>
      <span> 1</span>
      <span>C</span>
      <span>/ </span>
      <span>ESS</span>
      <span>-</span>
      <span>LPDB</span>
      <span>/-/ </span>
      <span>C</span>
      <span>9</span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdlbg">
     <b>J;blftvsq htpekmnfn:</b>
    </td>
    <td class="td" colspan="4">
                       D cjjndtncndbb c nf,kbwtq

    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdlbg">
     <b>Ntcnjdfz ghjwtlehf:</b>
    </td>
    <td class="td" colspan="4">Cvjnhb nf,kbwe dfhbfynjd Ntcnjdjuj ckexfz</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdlbg">
     <b>Rjvtynfhbq:</b>
    </td>
    <td class="td" colspan="4"/>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <p> </p>
  <table class="table">
   <tr>
    <td class="tdmbg" colspan="4">
     <b>Dfhbfyns NC/J;blftvst htpekmnfns</b>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdmbg" width="5%">
     <b>G/g</b>
    </td>
    <td class="tdmbg" width="33%">
     <b>TC</b>
    </td>
    <td class="tdmbg" width="33%">
     <b>Gjkj;tybt cfvjk`nf</b>
    </td>
    <td class="tdmbg" width="33%">
     <b>ТP</b>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdmbg">1</td>
    <td class="tdmbg"> TC-IMA-007.001</td>
    <td class="tdmbg"> yf ptvkt (WOW=True)</td>
    <td class="tdmbg"> TP-IMA-004</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdc" width="20%" colspan="2" rowspan="5">
     <b>J;blftvsq htpekmnfn</b>
    </td>
    <td class="tdc" width="10%">J,sxysq</td>
    <td class="td" width="70%" colspan="1">
     <p>
      <span style="color: #000000">Yf cbuyfkmyjv gjkt rflhf </span>
      <span style="color: #000000">EWD</span>
      <span style="color: #000000"> bylbwbhetncz</span>
      <span style="color: #E36C0A"> </span>
      <span style="color: #000000">ntrcnjdjt</span>
      <span style="color: #E36C0A"> </span>
      <span style="color: #000000">ghtleght;lf.ott cjj,otybt rfntujhbb Caution</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span style="color:#FF8C00">SWS 1 FAULT</span>
      <span style="color: #000000"> zynfhyjuj wdtnf.</span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdc" width="10%">J,sxysq</td>
    <td class="td" width="70%" colspan="1">
     <p>
      <span style="color: #000000">Yf cbuyfkmyjv gjkt rflhf </span>
      <span style="color: #000000">EWD</span>
      <span style="color: #000000"> bylbwbhetncz</span>
      <span style="color: #E36C0A"> </span>
      <span style="color: #000000">ntrcnjdjt</span>
      <span style="color: #E36C0A"> </span>
      <span style="color: #000000">ghtleght;lf.ott cjj,otybt rfntujhbb Caution</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span style="color:#FF8C00">FWS 1 FAULT</span>
      <span style="color: #000000"> zynfhyjuj wdtnf.</span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdc" width="10%">
       zCNJ</td>
    <td class="td" width="70%" colspan="1">
     <p>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">
           zCNJ: </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">Ntrcn jnrfpf </span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000">TBD</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000">,</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD"> rjl jnrfpf </span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000">TBD</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD"> bylbwbhetncz yf vytvjrflht </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">БСТО</span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdc" width="10%">BCCRJH</td>
    <td class="td" width="70%" colspan="1">
     <p>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">BCCRJH: </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">Byajhvfwbz</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000"> </span>
      <span>jnrfp cbcntvs ghtleght;ltybz j cdfkbdfybb</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000"> </span>
      <span>(</span>
      <span>SWS</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>is</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>fault</span>
      <span>)</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">, </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">byltrc byajhvfwbb </span>
      <span>1.5.3</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD"> pfhtubcnhbhjdfyf</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD"> </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">d </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">BCCRJH</span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdc" width="10%">BCCRJH</td>
    <td class="td" width="70%" colspan="1">
     <p>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">BCCRJH: </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">Byajhvfwbz</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000"> CAS_MES_</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000">TBD</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000"> </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">byltrc byajhvfwbb </span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000">1.11.</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000">TBD</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD"> pfhtubcnhbhjdfyf</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD"> </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">d </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">BCCRJH</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD"> (ghjcvjnh gjckt bcgsnfybz)</span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdmbg">2</td>
    <td class="tdmbg"> TC-IMA-007.002</td>
    <td class="tdmbg"> D djple[t (WOW=FALSE)</td>
    <td class="tdmbg"> TP-IMA-008</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdc" width="20%" colspan="2" rowspan="5">
     <b>J;blftvsq htpekmnfn</b>
    </td>
    <td class="tdc" width="10%">J,sxysq</td>
    <td class="td" width="70%" colspan="1">
     <p>
      <span>Yf cbuyfkmyjv gjkt rflhf </span>
      <span>EWD</span>
      <span> bylbwbhetncz ntrcnjdjt ghtleght;lf.ott cjj,otybt rfntujhbb </span>
      <span>Caution</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span style="color:#FF8C00">SWS 1 FAULT</span>
      <span> янтарного цвета</span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdc" width="10%">J,sxysq</td>
    <td class="td" width="70%" colspan="1">
     <p>
      <span>Yf cbuyfkmyjv gjkt rflhf </span>
      <span>EWD</span>
      <span> bylbwbhetncz ntrcnjdjt ghtleght;lf.ott cjj,otybt rfntujhbb </span>
      <span>Caution</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span style="color:#FF8C00">FWS 1 FAULT</span>
      <span> янтарного цвета</span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdc" width="10%">
           zCNJ</td>
    <td class="td" width="70%" colspan="1">
     <p>
      <span>
               zCNJ^ Ntrcn jnrfpf </span>
      <span>TBD</span>
      <span>, rjl jnrfpf </span>
      <span>TBD</span>
      <span> bylbwbhetncz yf vytvjrflht zCNJ</span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdc" width="10%">BCCRJH</td>
    <td class="td" width="70%" colspan="1">
     <p>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">BCCRJH: </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">Byajhvfwbz</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000"> </span>
      <span>jnrfp cbcntvs ghtleght;ltybz j cdfkbdfybb</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000"> </span>
      <span>(</span>
      <span>SWS</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>is</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>fault</span>
      <span>)</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">, </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">byltrc byajhvfwbb </span>
      <span>1.5.3</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD"> pfhtubcnhbhjdfyf</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD"> </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">d </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">BCCRJH</span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdc" width="10%">BCCRJH</td>
    <td class="td" width="70%" colspan="1">
     <p>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">BCCRJH: </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">Byajhvfwbz</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000"> CAS_MES_</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000">TBD</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000"> </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">byltrc byajhvfwbb </span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000">1.11.</span>
      <span style="color: #FF0000">TBD</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD"> pfhtubcnhbhjdfyf</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD"> </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">d </span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD">BCCRJH</span>
      <span style="color: #4F81BD"> (ghjcvjnh gjckt bcgsnfybz)</span>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <p>§</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
 font-family: "Times New Roman";
}

.table {
 width: 100%;
 border: 0px outset;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-left-width: 1px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 font-size: 11px;
}

.td > table {
 width: 100%;
 border: 0px outset;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-left-width: 1px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 font-size: 11px;
}

.th, .td {
 border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
 border-style: inset;
 border-color: #000000;
 padding: 5px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.td > th, td {
 border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
 border-style: inset;
 border-color: #000000;
 padding: 5px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.tdc {
 border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
 border-style: inset;
 border-color: #000000;
 padding: 5px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}

.tdwu {
 border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px; 
 border-style: inset;
 border-color: #000000;
 padding: 5px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.tdm {
 border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
 border-style: inset;
 border-color: #000000;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}

.tdmbg {
 border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
 border-style: inset;
 border-color: #000000;
 background: #F2F2F2;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}

.tdlbg {
 border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
 border-style: inset;
 border-color: #000000;
 background: #F2F2F2;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;
}

.text {
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 11px;
}

p {
 padding: 5px;
}

.caption {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 5px;
}

.text > table > tr > th {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #F2F2F2;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

.text > table {
 width: 100%;
 border: 0px outset;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-left-width: 1px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 font-size: 11px;
}

.text > table > tr > th, td {
 border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
 border-style: inset;
 border-color: #000000;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;
}

.fix {
 color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks for fix screenshot

Comment: Can you please share a minimal HTML snippet that causes the issue to appear? Without it, it's hard to reproduce the problem and as a result, provide advice.

Comment: thanks for response..  my HTML generated by path xml --> xslt --> HTML.. Ok, I'll make problem HTML fragment, also using css styles for it html and  page size config

Comment: I updated post with example html and css.. I create page like  page = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4); and make body rectangle like body = new Rectangle(56, 60, 553, 757);  after I make HTML+CSS transformation XMLParser to ElementList and fill it to body instance

Comment: Please add the specifics of your code using iText to the ticket, someone interested in answering your question should have access to all they need to reproduce your issue. That includes what you've just put in the comments.